# Was Kuuya's regression caused by Hakuro?

Tags: utawarerumono

In the aftermath of the battle with Kuuya, Kuuya's mind regresses to a child too, as Sakuya explains

> To go back to a time when she had no worries

Hakuro blames himself as he had transformed, and when he approached her she was screaming and clawing out of her Mecha. However, throughout the story Hakuro blames himself when he is able to help people close to him. And before Kuuya regressed, not only was Genjimaru killed, but Dii also attacked her, leaving her Mecha badly damaged.

I am wondering if it was really Hakuro being transformed that caused Kuuya to regress (out of fear) or if it were other factors that had occurred at that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess would be the preceding events before Hakuoro's transformation. I'm going to go with the game's depiction of the scene for the most part.

The game shows more happening to Kuuya mostly due to the fact that she's awake through the whole event, rather than lying there unconscious which the anime shows. She learns of Hien and Hauenkua's betrayal and their allegiance with Dii, causing her to attack them after Dii kills Genjimaru. What the anime doesn't show is that she's still in her Avu Kamuu during the time of the attack, rather than having it damaged beyond repair during her fight with Hakuoro. Also, she is attacked directly by Hauenkua and Dii (in his transformed state)

Before she sees what's left of Genji, Hakuoro, in his transformed state, tries to console her and make her calm down. However, seeing what Dii was at the time and Hakuoro directly mimicking his appearance, Kuuya screams at him to get away, thinking that he's the same one who attacked her. She tries to escape by falling out of the Avu Kamuu, but unfortunately ends up landing right next to the remains of Genji, finally realizing what happened.

To bring up the anime, Kuuya sees what happens to Genji, causing her to react the same way. While she does see Hakuoro fighting in his transformed state it isn't as overt as the game's depiction of the same scene and that she doesn't see most of it. I think the biggest impact on her was Genji being murdered right in front of her.

So, I think while Hakuoro may have had some hand at it, it was more of a combination of events. Hope this helps!

Comment: i didn't think of Hakuro looking like Gii and thus being mistaken for Genjimaru killer being a factor and i totally forgot how Hien and Hauenkua's betrayal being revealed to Kuuya being here instead of when Hien having his view twisted and siding for domination